# Как для TextView задать программно стиль?

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

Например:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(PhotoActivity.this);
    textView.setText("Photo not found.");
```

Тогда как задать стиль?

```
textView.set...???
```

Мне нужно было сделать цвет текста и позиционирование по центру программно, я решил задачку:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    TextView textView = new TextView(PhotoActivity.this);
    textView.setText("Photo not found.");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Как вариант так:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Ниже вам подсказали правильный вариант, но если у вас подобное форматирование встречается в приложении лишь единожды, то стиль вообще не нужен. Стиль - это набор визуальных атрибутов, который обычно массово переиспользуется в приложении. Для уникального компонента не нужно создавать стиль - оставьте так, как есть у вас сейчас.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам поможет

```
textView.setTextAppearance(int styleResId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textView59.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Это, ксожалению, невозможно.
Но выход есть: Создать `xml` файл с `TextView` с нужным стилем:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/your_style">

</TextView>
```

И дальше программно его инфлейтить:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.styled_textView, null);
```

Если хочется именно программно выбрать стиль, не создавая отдельную разметку для каждого стиля, можете сохранить один вариант разметки где-нибудь в `assets`, дальше загружать его, как обычный `XML`-документ, изменять ему атрибут `style`, и скармливать `LayoutInflater`у в этот [метод](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup))