# Задать XML-атрибут "style" элементу "TextView" программно

Tags: android, android-textview, android-style

Есть `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/a"
    style="@style/textview_style" />
```

А как создать такой же `TextView` программно? Если быть точнее, то мой вопрос заключается в том, как программно задать атрибут стиля **в API level 8.** Такой код

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(this);
mTextView.setText(R.string.a);
mTextView.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.game_TextView_n); //requires API 23
```

годится только для API level 23 и выше.

Вот стиль, который должен быть задан для `TextView`:

```
<style name="game_TextView_n">

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/game_textview_cell_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/game_TextView_cell_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/game_TextView__textSize</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как для TextView задать программно стиль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484111/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-textview-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: @woesss, не совсем. Во-первых, я не знаю какого типа стиль там требуется задать, у меня это конкретно стиль для конкретного `TextView` в *styles.xml*. Во-вторых, в том вопросе нет подходящих ответов: принятый ответ требует API level 23, второй ответ задаёт стиль к тексту, а не к `TextView`, а третий ответ является отрицательным, то бишь невозможно такое сделать, в чём я очень сомневаюсь - в Android можно сделать всё, что угодно, если захотеть и "знать Android от а до я" (если так можно сказать :)

Comment: Тогда Вы что-то путаете - у Вас в вопросе метод не требует `API 23`, а наоборот объявлен в этом API устаревшим и предлагает аналог с одним параметром. [`developer.android.com: TextView.setTextAppearance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance(android.content.Context,%20int))

Comment: Указать стиль как в вашем вопросе вы можете только через [конструктор виджета](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int)) при его создании. Для изменения отдельных атрибутов виджета программно есть отдельные методы, как  `setBackground()` и тд. все сразу, после создания виджета, изменить нельзя, даже зная Android от ! до �

Comment: @pavlofff, я пробовал таким образом `TextView mTextView = new TextView(this, null, R.style.game_TextView_n)` - стиль вообще не задаётся, даже для текста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613069/7566397

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, работает! Но, почему-то, `LayoutParams` приходиться каждый раз программно указывать `mTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));`, без этой строки в компоновке всё сдвигается. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: @pavlofff, т. е. получается, что у моего `TextView` без этой строки присваивается ширина `WRAP_CONTENT`, а не `MATCH_PARENT`, как указано в стиле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот работающий способ:

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.game_TextView_n), null, 0);
```

Comment: Я всё ещё жду новых ответов. Возможно, этот вариант не самый оптимальный + я не профессионал в Android, вдруг этот способ не является наилучшим в моём случае.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два метода `TextView.setTextAppearance` - один был с `API 1`, другой пришёл ему на смену в `API 23`. Что бы правильно использовать такие методы делают условие по уровню API:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            mTextView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.game_TextView_n);
        else
            //noinspection deprecation
            mTextView.setTextAppearance(R.style.game_TextView_n);
}
```

Comment: Нет, не работает. Стиль задаётся только для самого текста, т. е. не игнорируются только атрибуты `android:textStyle`, `android:textSize`, и т. п. А атрибут, например, `android:background` не работает. Изменил вопрос.

Comment: Ну Вы же задаёте **Text** Appearance. Насколько я понимаю общая тема оформления в принципе задаётся при создании вью и после не меняется. Попробуйте использовать конструктор с атрибутами, а лучше опишите Ваш `TextView` в xml и создавайте с помощью `LayoutInflater`. **P.S.** Для изменения `background` - есть соответствующий метод, для некоторых других атрибутов тоже есть методы-аналоги.

Comment: Я задаю не Text Appearance, а **стиль для элемента: `style="@style/game_TextView_n"`** - пример задания стиля XML-кодом в компоновке. *Я решил проблему (см. ответ ниже).*